# How to hide a spammy mention on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, spam-prevention

On the `Twitter > @Mentions` tab, is it possible to hide a spammy mention there?

I got some unnecessary mentions from unknown Twitter users (I'm suspicious it's not even a person), its tweet is `click this link` and that's it. I don't even think to click his/her/its Twitter profile. It's really annoying since I sometimes need to check the `@Mentions` tab if my followers and friends talk with me. I follow users based on my interest, not only because that user is my friend, anyway.

What should I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you get spammy messages like that, click on their username to bring the account up on the panel on the right.  Click on the button which looks like a head and shoulders with a dropdown arrow, and report them for spam, which will remove their posts from your timeline (you can also choose to block them from that same menu, but this kills two birds with one stone).
[image]

Comment: Whoa it's working! Thanks! FYI some of them are not my followers, but **reporting them for spam** successfully removed their spammy mention at my twitter's mention timeline tab.

Comment: @Arie Yes, you are correct that they don't have to be following you.  I chose that screencap just to show where the icon was, and I picked the most generic user I could think of.